# How to disable inclusion of header when using `#pragma once` (similiary to when using include guards)?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, include, pragma, include-guards

From time to time I have to retrofit unit testing into an unfriendly environment.
In these cases include guards are pretty useful, because:

1. I could suppress inclusion of unwanted header file,
2. I could check whether specific file was (not)included into test environment.

It seems that both these options are gone with `#pragma once`.

Are there any workarounds beyond replacing `#pragma` with guards for critical files?

Comment: You can add header guards to those files, and keep the `#pragma once` (inside the header guard) as well.  (Some compilers let you put the pragma anywhere, some really want it to be near the beginning.)

Comment: I've found that using the pimpl pattern can be a big help here too. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). It might even do some good for your overall build times since code using your class and its implementation part can compile in parallel.

Comment: In the particular situation you describe, I suggest you would be better off replacing usage of `#pragma once` with include guards.  If you really want use both, place the `#pragma once` for a header inside its include guards.   Of the two, I generally lean toward using include guards since they are standardised (consistency between compilers) while `#pragma`s can introduce subtle (and sometimes not so subtle) inconsistency between compilers  [and, in my work, conformance with standards is a critical consideration].